# Javascript when tab 2 is click, it will block the UI but tab 1 must be active

Tags: javascript

I have 2 tabs: **vehicle** and **geozone**. What I need to do is when I clicked geozone tab, it will block the UI using `blockUI` but after the blockUI, the active tab must be the vehicle tab. Is there a way to do it inside the JavaScript and not use the `onclick` on PHP?

I have this click function for the geozone tab:

```
$("#mapContainer").on("click", ".tabs2", function(){
    console.log("tab tabs2 clicked");
    $.blockUI({ 
        message: '<h1>Geozone is not available in Windy Map.</h1>',
        css: { 
        border: 'none', 
        padding: '15px', 
        backgroundColor: '#000', 
        '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
        '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
        opacity: .5, 
        color: '#fff' 
    } }); 

    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 
});
```

and I have this for the PHP:

```
<div id="tabs1">
  <ul style="margin: 1px -2px 0px 2px;">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" class="tabs1">Vehicle</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2" class="tabs2">Geozone</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `$.blockUI()` *is* JavaScript. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @ObsidianAge when i clicked the tab-2 which is the geozone, it will block the ui but afte the timeout, the tab-1 which is the vehicle tab must be active. that's what im asking. ill edit the post to make it clear. im sorry

Comment: the selecter should be $("#mapContainer .tabs2")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that, you click on tab to activate it. You can use `onUnblock` callback.

```
$('#mapContainer').on('click', '.tabs2', function() {
    $.blockUI({ 
        message: '<h1>Geozone is not available in Windy Map.</h1>',
        css: { 
            border: 'none', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#000', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .5, 
            color: '#fff'
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function() { 
        $.unblockUI({ 
            onUnblock: function() { $('.tabs1').trigger('click'); } 
        }); 
    }, 2000); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like after click tabs2, trigger click tabs1?

```
$("#mapContainer").on("click", ".tabs2", function(){
    console.log("tab tabs2 clicked");
    $.blockUI({ 
        message: '<h1>Geozone is not available in Windy Map.</h1>',
        css: { 
        border: 'none', 
        padding: '15px', 
        backgroundColor: '#000', 
        '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
        '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
        opacity: .5, 
        color: '#fff' 
    } }); 

    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 

    $(".tabs1").trigger("click");  //new
});

// new
$("#mapContainer").on("click", ".tabs1", function(){
    console.log("click tabs1");
});
```